# Why typescript does not properly infer T[K] with <T extends Person, K extends keyof T> generic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have created a React hook:

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
}

export const usePerson = function <T extends Person, K extends keyof T>(): (property: K, setter: (value: T[K]) => T[K]) => void {

    const setPersonProperty = (property: K, setter: (value: T[K]) => T[K]): void => {
        console.log(property, setter)
    }

    setPersonProperty('name', (x) => x)

    return setPersonProperty;
}
```

I have seen the pattern `<T, K extends keyof T>` from typescript docs but I am unable to use it correctly in my example.

More specifically, the typescript complains on the line

```
setPersonProperty('name', (x) => x)
```

Although when I start typing `setPersonProperty('n /* IDE autocompletes name */` but complains for the `'name'` parameter and I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.   'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
```

I have also posted an image from my IDE. I am using typescript 4+.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet that this is the result You want to achieve

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    age: number
};

export const usePerson = function <T extends Person>() {
    const setPersonProperty = <K extends keyof T> (property: K, setter: (value: T[K]) => T[K]): void => {
        console.log(property, setter)
    }

    setPersonProperty("name", (x) => x)

    return setPersonProperty;
}

 const setPerson = usePerson<Person>()

 setPerson("name", (name) => name)
```

Basically, in code you provided there are two generic types when calling this usePerson hook `T` and `K` (`<T extends Person, K extends keyof T>`).

Let's say someone will call this function with `usePerson<Person, "age">()`.
What typescript will do it will replace types inside our `usePerson` to be `T = Person` and `K = "age"`

And now you have a mismatch since `setPersonProperty` have first argument of type K ("age") the argument "name" is not assignable - that the error you see.